# layout doesnt arrange as per screen orientation change multiple times in api10

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.3-gingerbread, landscape-portrait

im working with my android app, where i used

> ```
>           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
> ```

so that the data from sqlite are not loaded all the time.
it worked well for api 10 and api 18.
i tested both of them by changing the orientation portrait and landscape a multiple times.

but now i am using api library AppCompat to add official action bar.
the problem now is that using api18 and changing the orientation a multiple time,everything works as it should.

but changing orientation from

> PORTRAIT to LANDSCAPE and back to PORTRAIT for api10

the data is still displayed as landscape.
[image: api10 doesnot change back the data to its orientation]
i am using GridView for portait numCol=1. landscape numCol=2.
so for api10 when its in portrait mode it displays only 1 column which is perfect. just it doesnot display it in portrait view

> left image API-18 and right image API-10

Comment: Can you post the code of your onConfigurationChanged method? Or are you using different layouts depending on the orientation?

Comment: I just specified in the manifest for the launcher activity, android:configChanges="..." I didnt use anycode for onconfigurationchanged. And im using same layout for portrait gridview column are set to 1 and for landscape gridview column are set 2. Both these xml are in different foldee

Comment: Do you have more qualifiers in those folders other than orientation?

Comment: No.. Just the default folders and an additional layout-land

Comment: Then, I think you should remove the `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` line from you xml, the documentation says that this means that you will handle those configuration changes by yourself, but you're not implementing a custom `onConfigurationChanged` method